# how to get after 6 month date in M / Y format?

Tags: php

How to get after 6 month date in M / Y format?
i try like this one but not working..

```
   $regDate = "Jan / 2013";
   $validTill = date('M / Y',strtotime("+6 months", strtotime($regDate)));
```

Comment: What do you mean, not working? What is the value of `$validTill`?

Comment: Can you be sure that you always got `$regDate` in `MON / yyyy` format?

Comment: what's the output of your current command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) object to convert your date.

```
$regDate = "Jan / 2013";
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('M / Y', $regDate);
$myDateTime->modify('+6 Months');
echo $myDateTime->format('M / Y');
```

**[CodePad DEMO.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/EoRROj)**

**Note:** It will support for PHP 5 >= 5.3.0 only.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the format to be readeable by `strtotime`.

```
$regDate = 'Jan / 2013';
// this should look likes this: 2013-01-01
```

Than your code will works.

And i Think better to store the dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` format (or as `unix timestamp`, but in this case you should use correct `time-zone`) , and when you show, convert it to the format what you need to display.